# Load Nested repeated if value matches - C#

Tags: c#, select, expression, repeater

I have a json feed with following data group:

```
["policy#:1111", "id:1", "name:abc"],
["policy#:1111", "id:2", "name:def"],
["policy#:2222", "id:3", "name:ghi"],
["policy#:2222", "id:4", "name:jkl"]
```

I want to group the records based on the "Policy#". so the data should display in repeater like this:

**Policy#: 1111**

id:1, Name:abc

id:2, Name:def

**Policy#: 2222**

id:3, Name: ghi

if:4, Name: jkl

I am using following code to achieve this but i can easily polupale Policy# on first repeater but i cannot display rest of the information based on policy# in nested repeater. Please help

Ascx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDocument" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repMenu1_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <ul id="getDocuments">
</HeaderTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <li class='parent'><%# Eval("Policynum") %></li>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="sub_repeater">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul id="getDocuments">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class='child'><%# Eval("Id") %>'</li>
            <li class='child'><%# Eval("Name") %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```

ASCX.CS (To bind data in nested repeater if policy# matches) This is where i am getting issues populating data in nested repeater

```
protected void repMenu1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType  == ListItemType.Item)
    {
      Repeater rptSub = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("sub_repeater");
      string searchExpression = "Policynum = '" + DataBinder.Eval((e.Item).DataItem, "Policynum") + "'";
        DataTable dt2 = buildData().Select(searchExpression).CopyToDataTable();
        rptSub.DataSource = buildData();
        rptSub.DataBind();
   }
}
```

After running the above code, i am getting the result like this:

**Policy#:1111**

id:1,Name:abc

id:2,Name:def

id:3,Name:ghi

id:4,Name:jkl

**Policy#:2222**

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your code:

```
DataTable dt2 = buildData().Select(searchExpression).CopyToDataTable();
rptSub.DataSource = buildData();
rptSub.DataBind();
```

The second line may be `rptSub.DataSource = dt2;`.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know how i missed it but now when i see the result, it is showing this result :
Policy#:1111
id:1,Name:abc
id:2,Name:def
Policy#2

Comment: All right than. According to your code, maybe you want to `Select` some data from the result of `buildData()` method and `CopyToDataTable()` dt2. So I think the data source of `rptSub` should bind to the `DataTable` dt2, not the original `buildData()` method.